# Registrar datos de una Vista Parcial (popup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, asp.net-mvc

Trabajo con ASP.NET MVC 5, tengo una vista parcial la cual cuando presiono el botón Guardar debería de persistir los datos en la db y dirigirse al Index pero no esta registrando los datos. Muestro código.

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult CreatePV()
    {
        var documento = SdProveedor.Lista();
        ViewBag.ListaDocumento = new SelectList(documento, "Id", "Descripcion");

        var model = new ProveedorDto();
        return PartialView(model);
    }

    // POST: Proveedor/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ProveedorDto entity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //var documento = SdProveedor.Lista();
                //ViewBag.ListaDocumento = new SelectList(documento, "Id", "Descripcion");

                SdProveedor.Create(entity);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
                return View(entity);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(entity);
        }
    }
```

VIEW INDEX

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #337ab7;border-color:#2e6da4;color:#fff;">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h5 class="modal-title">Proveedor</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="resultado"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

PARTIAL VIEW

```
@model Demo.ServiciosDominio.Dtos.ProveedorDto

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    @*<h4>Proveedor</h4>
    <hr />*@
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RazonSocial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RazonSocial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RazonSocial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DocumentoIdentidad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.DocumentoIdentidad, "<<SELECCIONE>>", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DocumentoIdentidad, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Direccion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Direccion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Direccion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telefono, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telefono, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telefono, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @*<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-default" />
                <input type="button" value="Cerrar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>*@
    </div>
    }
```

HTML GENERADO

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Proveedor - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Home">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">


<h3>Proveedor</h3>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="/Content/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



    <script src="/scripts/botonFlotanteDespegable.js"></script>
    <link href="/Content/css/botonFlotante.css" rel="stylesheet" />



</head>
<body>


    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="contenedor">
        <button class="botonF1">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
        </button>

        <button class="botonFlotante botonF4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt span.glyphicon"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="botonFlotante botonF5" onclick="llamarVistaParcial();" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table id="proveedores" class="table table-hover display">
                <thead style="background-color:#337ab7;border-color:#2e6da4;color:#fff;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>ProveedorId</td>
                        <td>Razón Social</td>
                        <td>Número documento</td>
                        <td>Dirección</td>
                        <td>Teléfono</td>
                        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>


                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>COMERCIAL PEPITA</td>
                            <td>10617044</td>
                            <td>MI CASA</td>
                            <td>25454547</td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>LA FABRICA</td>
                            <td>45645</td>
                            <td>BABAHOYO</td>
                            <td>45612</td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>dfsdfsdfsdf</td>
                            <td>3434343</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>PEDRO &#193;VILA N&#218;&#209;EZ</td>
                            <td>10617044</td>
                            <td>MI CASA</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>HOLA</td>
                            <td>123456</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6</td>
                            <td>HOLA 2</td>
                            <td>00000</td>
                            <td>XXXXX</td>
                            <td>3333</td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>7</td>
                            <td>HOLA 3</td>
                            <td>111</td>
                            <td>BABAHOYO</td>
                            <td>333</td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>8</td>
                            <td>GDGDFGDFG</td>
                            <td>DFGDFG</td>
                            <td>DFGDFGD</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>9</td>
                            <td>DESIGE</td>
                            <td>00125452</td>
                            <td>FDGDFGFDG53453</td>
                            <td>DFGDFG</td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>dfFDFD</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>11</td>
                            <td>fdsfsf</td>
                            <td>5454545</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>12</td>
                            <td>PRUEBA ER</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>13</td>
                            <td>dfGDFG</td>
                            <td>5454</td>
                            <td>RTE</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>14</td>
                            <td>flaco</td>
                            <td>4545454</td>
                            <td>mi casa</td>
                            <td>444</td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>15</td>
                            <td>dfdfd</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>16</td>
                            <td>babahoyo</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>17</td>
                            <td>fgfdgdfgdfgdgfdgffgf</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>18</td>
                            <td>hghghgg</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>19</td>
                            <td>FUNKO</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td>LESCANO</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>21</td>
                            <td>YOL FASHION</td>
                            <td>4578545</td>
                            <td>FGDGFDG</td>
                            <td>5656</td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>22</td>
                            <td>SDSA</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>





            <script src="/scripts/datatables.min.js"></script>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $("#proveedores").DataTable({
                        "language": {
                            "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
                            "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                            "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                            "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                            "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                            "sInfoPostFix": "",
                            "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                            "sUrl": "",
                            "sInfoThousands": ",",
                            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                            "oPaginate": {
                                "sFirst": "Primero",
                                "sLast": "Último",
                                "sNext": "Siguiente",
                                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                            },
                            "oAria": {
                                "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });


                //$('#btnF2').on('click', function(e){
                //    alert('your are click me');
                //});
            </script>
            <script>
                function llamarVistaParcial() {
                    var laURLDeLaVista = '/Proveedor/CreatePV';
                    $.ajax({
                        cache: false,
                        async: true,
                        type: "GET",
                        url: laURLDeLaVista,
                        data: {},
                        success: function (response) {
                            //$('#resultado').html('');
                            $('#resultado').html(response);
                            $("#myModal").modal('show');
                        }
                    });
                    //$("#myModal").modal('show');
                };
            </script>




<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"1e767ad044ff4fd8a95e31aa6c8a2046"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:13758/465bd761a53b4c66824603acd0acf201/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #337ab7;border-color:#2e6da4;color:#fff;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h5 class="modal-title">Proveedor</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="resultado"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>







        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2017 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué te renderiza la vista parcial? Muestra el HTML generado por favor :D

Comment: Para utilizar el token, agrega [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  en tu HttpPost :D

Comment: dónde está el formulario <form> ?

Comment: @fredyFx Exactamente a donde te refieres

Comment: ¿En qué parte se supone que debe aparecer?

Comment: @fredyfx un favor podrías dar tu respuesta pero haciendolo con ajax, me interesa mucho hacerlo con ajax por que voy a necesitar enviar mensajes

Comment: esa es otra pregunta. ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Has buscado cómo hacer formularios mediante Ajax? Vamo al chat :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que alcanzo a entender con el código que estas mostrando, cuando abres la ventana modal todo el contenido de la vista parcial lo estas poniendo en

```
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Si esto es correcto, el error radica en que el botón `submit` que utilizas para guardar queda por fuera del `form`.

Te recomiendo que le quites el comentario a los botones que tienes dentro de la vista parcial, muy seguramente con estos si te va a funcionar.

Ahora bien, si quieres conservar los botones en el `footer` como los estas diseñando debes cambiar la ubicación del form

**INDEX**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create","NombreDelControlador")) 
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade in">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #337ab7;border-color:#2e6da4;color:#fff;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h5 class="modal-title">Proveedor</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="resultado"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    }
```

para que te abarque toda la ventana modal y tu vista parcial debería quedar así,

**VISTA PARCIAL**

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @*<h4>Proveedor</h4>
    <hr />*@
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RazonSocial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RazonSocial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RazonSocial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DocumentoIdentidad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.DocumentoIdentidad, "<<SELECCIONE>>", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DocumentoIdentidad, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Direccion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Direccion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Direccion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telefono, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telefono, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telefono, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @*<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-default" />
                <input type="button" value="Cerrar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>*@
    </div>
```

Comment: Los botones que tienen que persistir son los que puse en el footer

Comment: @PedroÁvila Ya actualice la respuesta, con un ejemplo de como debería quedar mas o menos el código

Comment: Modificastes algo en la vista parcial?

Comment: No nada, solo que la vista parcial ya no tendría la instrucción `@using (Html.BeginForm()) {}`

Comment: Tendría Que modifica el nombre del método del controler Create a CreatePV?

Comment: Depurando no hay conexión entre mi Vista Parcial con el método de acción CreatePV

Comment: No te entiendo muy bien cuando me dices que no hay conexión, pero te puedo decir que puedes controlar cual es la acción que quieres ejecutar cuando se presione el botón `submit`, esto lo haces así: `@using(Html.BeginForm("NombreDeLaAccion", "NombreDelControlador")){}`

Comment: Modifica tu respuesta tienes mi código para poner donde va el cambio

Comment: OK, ya está. Solo cambia el INDEX en la declaración del form. Basta con que pongas el nombre de tu controlador

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("CreatePV", "Proveedor"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade in">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:

Comment: Ahora si funciono gracias!!!

Comment: Que bien!!! Me alegra que te haya funcionado